# Android SMS limit on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, sms

I am working with phone with Android 4.0.4 (I know, the old one)
Now I need to override limit of 100 sms send per hour (Below android 4.1 there should be limit 100 sms per hour. Since android 4.1 there is limit 30 sms per 30 minutes). 
Since Android 4.2 it is possible via adb shell settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count.
But I have no idea how to do it on Android 4.0.4 without rooting because there is no "adb shell settings" command. Any idea?

P.S. I am not creating app. I need to override this limit ideally in android settings via adb or by using another app for this (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by creating the application and overriding the [SmsUsageMonitor](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/932e8e5dacd4e154d5c7b94f396a4d32de931551/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsUsageMonitor.java):
`com.android.internal.telephony.SmsUsageMonitor`

It should basically work on any phone, without rooting it first.

Comment: I am not creating app. I need to override this limit ideally in android settings via adb or by using another app for this (if it exists)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to follow theses steps via ADB :

- 1.Open **Command Terminal**
- 2.Type in **adb shell hit enter**
- 3.Type in **su** hit enter
- 4.Type in **sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db** hit enter
- 5.Type in **INSERT INTO secure (name, value) VALUES('sms_outgoing_check_max_count’, 9999);** hit enter
- 6.Type in I**NSERT INTO system (name, value) VALUES('sms_outgoing_check_max_count’, 9999);** hit enter
- 7.Type in **.exit** hit enter (you should now see a hash tag again instead of sqlite>. If not conitune typing in .exit and hitting enter until you are)
- 8.Type in **sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.gsf/databases/gservices.db**
- 9.Type in **INSERT INTO main (name, value) VALUES('sms_outgoing_check_max_count’, 9999);** hit enter
- 10.Again exit back to where the command line has a hashtag
- 11.Type in **reboot** and hit enter.

I don't have a phone with Android 4.0.4, so i can't confirm that it will work

Happy testing !

Answer (score 0):

you have to use abd command to open that restrictions here is the link for tutorial  [change sms limit](https://www.xda-developers.com/change-sms-limit-android/)

1.Go to the android platform tool directory

```
 `(C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools)``enter code here`
```

2. open command shell by using Shift+mouserightclick and enter this command

   `adb shell settings put global sms_outgoing_check_max_count 5`

   `settings put global sms_outgoing_check_interval_ms 9000000`

I am actually reducing the number so Android warns me if I have sent more than 5 SMS messages within 30(9000000) minutes. Change “5” to whatever number you want

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want to acheive with over 100 SMS per hour?
I am sure there is a way more efficient way of sending your data for example through
a wireless network or mobile data. You would hardly manage to reach the data limits of
those networks.

Just saying ... try only to do it over SMS if there really is **NO** other way of sending it.

Good luck!